# Cruise control not working

Tags: dodge, cruise-control

I have a 1999 Dodge Dakota.  Roughly a month ago my cruise control stopped working.  When I turn on the cruise control I get the light showing that it is on.  However, when I try to engage/set the cruise control it doesn't do anything.  What would cause my cruise control to suddenly not work anymore?  Could it be a fuse?

I saw another post on here that the brake lights and cruise control don't work.  I am not experiencing that issue.  My brake lights are working fine.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bad switch.  Assuming the main cruise control system is responding but you aren't getting set, reset, coast, etc., then it's likely that one or more of the internal contacts has broken or come loose.

Annoyingly, those control stalks are [integrated units](http://www.jcwhitney.com/cruise-control-kits/dodge-dakota/c20224d412j1s21.jcwx).  Easy to replace but not cheap.